# Config the Anaconda with PyDev/Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, anaconda, pydev

I'd like to have an Anaconda under PyDev/ECLIPSE IDE. I used the default installation of Anaconda where no Win10 environmental PATH has been set up. I guess PyDev auto-configurer can't find Anaconda installation now.

[image]

What/How to configure properly Anaconda with PyDev/Eclipse - can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse/Menu -> Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Python Interpreter

New ...  -> choose from conda and add available env :)

[image]

Set as Default the env you want to use - then indicated in a python project which env/interpreter is used.

Don't know if there is a better solution though.

[image]